# Contributing to magento hackathon Github

Tags: magento2, magento-community

I'm wanting to contribute to the magento hackathon github page https://github.com/magento-hackathon .Does it need to be during a hackathon or can anyone contribute at anytime? And Do they accept PR's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just thought I'd pipe up and offer some additional perspective.  I'm a member of the GitHub org and the admin for our Magento Hackathon Team Chat (I also run the twitter account with a few other admins / writers).

The short answer is YES - please feel free to contribute to any repository and submit your PR's.  I'd recommend a few things to smooth that process out for you:

1. Check to see if there's any open issues relating to your idea and if not, file an issue first in the repo.  That will get the attention of the project's maintainers.
2. Reach out the to the project maintainers via email, if possible.  The repos are owned & maintained by a very diverse group of devs across many countries and companies and some are more active than others.  Also, leading up to public events like the Pre-Imagine Hackathon, activity tends to begin increasing so it's best to just introduce yourself and see if there's anything they have planned that hasn't made it to the repo yet.
3. Consider requesting an invite to join our team slack at https://slofile.com/slack/magento-hackathon - it's now automated and you should get a response pretty quickly with your login info and you can use that forum to reach out with questions!
4. Follow Us on Twitter at https://twitter.com/mage_hackathon

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to contact them directly as they are the only ones who can answer your questions:
https://www.mage-hackathon.de/contacts/